# Changing LSMinimumSystemVersion in Mac OS X installer created with install4j

Tags: macos, install4j, dmg

I'm creating Mac OS X installers with the version 5.1.6 of install4j. The generated Info.plist file containes the definition for LSMinimumSystemVersion = 10.6. I need to be able to change this to 10.5.

I've modified the generated DMG file and it works fine. But I would prefer to have install4j using the correct minimum Mac OS X version.

I haven't found any information in the install4j help nor with a google search.

Anybody of you already done this and can help me out?

Answer (score 1):

This entry is only present in the Info.plist file if you use Oracle JRE launchers, i.e. for Java 7 and higher. Oracle JREs do not work reliably with Mac OS 10.5. There is no way to change this entry in install4j.